# best way to structure student grades database with variable columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

I'm trying to make a student grades retrieval system with PHP and MYSQL,the students from different stages study different subjects so I can't have one table for all students, instead I structured it so each stage has it's own table but I don't know what's the best way to search for a student in such structure.

The current structure is like this:-
first stage table:

```
CREATE TABLE `first stage` ( `ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,`name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
,`chemistry` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
,`physics` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
,`biology` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
,`avg` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL )
```

second stage table:

```
CREATE TABLE `second stage` ( `ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,`name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
,`math` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
,`english` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
,`french` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
,`avg` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL )
```

The `ID` columns contains a unique string generated randomly in php based on student name and a random number as a salt, this `ID` is given to the student so when he/she enters the ID in an html form the php script should select his/her grades from the mysql and display them

until now I have the student enter the ID and select his/her stage:- 
assuming the student submits a form with `$_POST['id'] = 6e34b0f66c` and `$_POST['stage'] = first stage` then the mysql query is used like this:

```
select * from `first stage` where ID='6e34b0f66c'
```

now I'm trying to eliminate the stage input so the student should only enter the ID and the php script should select from all the tables and return the correct result.

I tried to use union to query all the tables for the ID:

```
select * 
from `first stage` 
where ID='6e34b0f66c' 
union 
select * 
from `second stage` 
where ID='6e34b0f66c'
```

this works and returns the correct result but it lacks the table name(i.e it only returns the grades but I have no idea from which table the result came from so can't display the stage to the student).

I also tried to use multiple tables in the FROM clause:

```
select * from `second stage` `first stage` where ID='6e34b0f66c'
```

but I found out that this only queries the first table in the FROM clause and totally ignores the second one.

I can probably make a for loop in php to search the tables one by one and stop whenever the result is found in one of the tables but i think this would be inefficient and a solution in mysql is much preferred.

Comment: Bad design. Have a table for students, and another one for the courses. In a third table link student to courses. You can denote the "stage" (semester?) in the courses table if a course can only be taken in one "stage".

Comment: @stickybit can you provide an example ? where should the grades go? the students table?

Comment: The grades are part of the relation between a student and a course so they should go into the linking table.